# How do you begin a 16th note triplet on the last third of an eighth note triplet?

Tags: notation, composition, rhythm

My piece has a 16th note triplet motif.  In the B section, the theme is slower and is based on eighth note triplets.  I would like to begin the 16th triplet motif again on the last eighth note of an eighth note triplet but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Are you intending that the 16th-note triplet will exactly replace the final 8th-note within the triplet, or are you intending it to overlap into the following beat? (Also, what is the main time signature?)

Comment: To clarify, does your 16th-note triplet last 1/3 of a beat or 1/2 of a beat? Ordinarily, a 16th-note triplet is equivalent to a non-triplet eighth note.

Comment: Line 2 of the answer posted by @user1079505 is correct provided the 16th note motif has a 2 note pickup but your question is a little unclear. Does the 16th note triplet motif start with a pickup or a downbeat? If it starts with a downbeat then you are better off writing the 8th note triplet section as 12/8 (provided it is in 4/4 and has a triplet feel throughout) and the last bar of 8th note triplets to be 11/8.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy right, I made some assumptions. You could interpret the question differently. It would be great if OP could post some excerpts from the score he's working on.

Comment: @user1079505 I actually conceived the answer the way you wrote it initially as well but then I thought “What if the sixteenth is a new downbeat?”. There’s not enough information to give a truly accurate answer, even after comments have been posted requesting more info. That seems to happen a lot with new contributors.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to achieve as an eight-note triplet lasts the same time as two sixteen-note triplets. See the following example.

[image]